# Git branching from a feature branch to work on a subfeature

Tags: git, branching

We're currently in the following situation, where a feature branch has been branched for a sub-feature branch (like, working on backend and frontend things for the same feature):

```
o 
|
o development
|\
| o feature-a
| |
| o
| |\
| | o feature-a-sub
| | |
| | |
|  \
|   o merged feature-a into feature-a-sub
|  /
o feature-a-sub merged into development
| |
| o feature-a with future work on it
|
o development
```

A developer first merged feature-a into his feature-a-sub branch to be up-to-date, and then merged his feature-a-sub into development. Whereas the initial feature-a branch is still existent, and not yet finished.

In my point of view, this yields the problem that the feature-a branch is now rendered obsolete, as all changes are merged into feature-a-sub and then into development. In addition, work has continued on feature-a, which leads to future merge conflicts and a lot of manual labor.

Where did we take the wrong turn, and how would a proper workflow with less trouble look like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One *should* only merge to and from parent branch.  For `feature-a-sub`, this is `feature-a`, not `development`.

Merging to the grandparent branch means that the reason that the parent branch was created hasn't been fulfilled, and yes, as noted this does create future problems where development continues on `feature-a` and `development` leading to an increased divergence of the code lines and more conflicts down the road.

This was assuming that `feature-a-sub` depended on the code in `feature-a`.  If `feature-a-sub` was instead independent of `feature-a`, it shouldn't have been branched from `feature-a` at all and instead should have been branched (and merged) into `development`.

If `feature-a` needed `feature-a-sub` to work (not sure it did as `feature-a` continued work without a merge of `feature-a-sub` into it), and `feature-a-sub` was independent of `feature-a`, `feature-a-sub` should instead have been `feature-b` with a branch from `development`, a merge back into `development`, and then either a merge of `development` or `feature-b` (if one doesn't want to pick up other changes from development) into `feature-a`.

The workflow should either be:

```
o                                        
|                                        
o development                            
|\                                       
| o feature-a                            
| |                                      
| o                                      
| |\                                     
| | o feature-a-sub                      
| | |                                    
| | |                                    
| | |                                    
| | o merged feature-a into feature-a-sub
| |/                                     
| o feature-a-sub merged into feature-a  
| |                                      
| o feature-a with future work on it     
|                                        
o development
```

or

```
o                                                  
|                                                  
o development                                      
|\                                                 
| \                                                
|  \                                               
|   o feature-a                                    
|\  |                                              
| b | feature-b                                    
| | |                                              
| | |                                              
| | |                                              
| b | feature-b complete                           
|/ \|                                              
o   o feature-b merged to development and feature-a
|   |                                              
|   o feature-a with future work on it
```

Related - a favorite read of mine on the *philosophy* of branching: [Advanced SCM Branching Strategies](http://www.vance.com/steve/perforce/Branching_Strategies.html).  While the white paper is targeted to centralized version control systems, the ideas behind the roles each branch can take are important in making sure you understand what is going on and can reason about what should be done next with any given branch.